# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: hbase

I am writing a spark program which will just put a record to hbase.
**Spark version 1.3.1
HBase 1.0.0-cdh5.4.2**
The program is as follows.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, HTable, Put}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HColumnDescriptor, HTableDescriptor}

object Employee {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.err.println("In correct number of arguments " + args.length)
      System.out.println("Please provide correct arguments.")
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val tableName = "employee"
    hbaseConf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","quickstart.cloudera")
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.client.port","2181")
    val admin = new HBaseAdmin(hbaseConf)
    val cfProfessionalData = Bytes.toBytes("professional_data")
    val cfPersonalData = Bytes.toBytes("personal_data")
    if (!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
      val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
      tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(cfProfessionalData))
      tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(cfPersonalData))
    }
    val hTable = new HTable(hbaseConf,tableName)
    //val records = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("e_1"))
    val eId = Bytes.toBytes("Emp_id")
    val name = Bytes.toBytes("Name")
    val dsgtn = Bytes.toBytes("Designation")
    val doj = Bytes.toBytes("DOJ")
    val addr = Bytes.toBytes("Address")
    val phn = Bytes.toBytes("Phone")
    val dob = Bytes.toBytes("DOB")
    put.add(cfProfessionalData, eId, Bytes.toBytes(1))
    put.add(cfProfessionalData, name, Bytes.toBytes("Mridul Gohain"))
    put.add(cfProfessionalData, dsgtn, Bytes.toBytes("SE"))
    put.add(cfProfessionalData, doj, Bytes.toBytes("15-07-2015"))
    put.add(cfPersonalData, addr, Bytes.toBytes("Chabua"))
    put.add(cfPersonalData, phn, Bytes.toBytes("9859559606"))
    put.add(cfPersonalData, dob, Bytes.toBytes("04-10-1991"))
    hTable.put(put)
    hTable.close()
  }
}
```

but when I execute the code, I get the below exception

```
16/08/03 04:09:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/cloudera
16/08/03 04:09:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cloudera/tars
16/08/03 04:09:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=quickstart.cloudera:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x3fa7e1a80x0, quorum=quickstart.cloudera:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager.getConnectionInternal(ConnectionManager.java:285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:207)
        at com.zaloni.mgohain.sparkHbaseIntegration.services.Employee$.main(Employee.scala:20)
        at com.zaloni.mgohain.sparkHbaseIntegration.services.Employee.main(Employee.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/Trace
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:218)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:481)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:850)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:635)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.Trace
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 26 more
16/08/03 04:09:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

Can you give some light here?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any help ?

Comment: I am facing same issue. let me know if you found solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware about the HBase version you are trying to access. Specially related with the htrace version that your hbase client is going to use. I set my pom.xml file to:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.htrace</groupId>
        <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
```

and it worked rightful.